# Avoiding long string for where in query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-in

I am developing an MLM website using php & Mysql. I have stored the parent_id of the member to the same table tbl_members.
Now i have to search in children of a member where the member may have 30,000 or more children in total (direct or indirect). How to do that.

What i am doing is, I just use a recursive function to take all the children ids (direct or indirect) as a comma separated string and pass them in my select statement. It works but takes time to calculate every time the children ids for making the string for **where in** statement in my select query.
What is the permanent solution. What would be the correct approach as the children may further increase to 100k or ever more.

Comment: Read about [nested sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model)

Comment: @Alma Do after reading the article (on your given link) i found its not good for large records.
Nested sets are very slow for inserts because it requires updating left and right domain values for all records in the table after the insert. This can cause a lot of database thrash[citation needed] as many rows are rewritten and indexes rebuilt.